# s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'schema' is invalid. Element 'complextype' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: xml, netbeans, xsd, schema

First of all, sorry for english, not my native language.

I have checked some post about this and the solution they was given was like "atributte below elements" but in this XML I dont have attributes. The complextype error is given to me in all the places I am using it. check it:

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<!DOCTYPE Layout SYSTEM "Layout.dtd">
<Layout>

    <Encabezado>
        <Campos1>
            <campo1>FechaDelReporte</campo1>
            <campo1>FechaEsperada</campo1>
        </Campos1>

        <TipoDatos1>
            <td1>Fecha</td1>
            <td1>Fecha</td1>
        </TipoDatos1>

        <Longitudes1>
            <lenght1>10</lenght1>
            <lenght1>10</lenght1>
        </Longitudes1>

        <Descripciones1>
            <descripcion1>FechaSeRealizoReporte</descripcion1>
            <descripcion1>FechaEnQueSeEsperaInformeConInformacion</descripcion1>
        </Descripciones1>
    </Encabezado>


    <Detalle>
        <Campos2>
            <campo2>Matricula</campo2>
            <campo2>Nombre</campo2>
            <campo2>CostoCredito</campo2>
            <campo2>CreditosACursar</campo2>
            <campo2>MontoCreditos</campo2>
        </Campos2>

        <TipoDatos2>
            <td2>Numerico</td2>
            <td2>Alfabetico</td2>
            <td2>Numerico</td2>
            <td2>Numerico</td2>
            <td2>Numerico</td2>
        </TipoDatos2>

        <Longitudes2>
            <lenght2>9</lenght2>
            <lenght2>50</lenght2>
            <lenght2>4</lenght2>
            <lenght2>2</lenght2>
            <lenght2>5</lenght2>
        </Longitudes2>

        <Descripciones2>
            <descripcion2>MatriculaEstudiante</descripcion2>
            <descripcion2>NombreEstudiante</descripcion2>
            <descripcion2>CostoDeCadaCredito</descripcion2>
            <descripcion2>CreditosCursaraEstudianteEnCuatrimestre</descripcion2>
            <descripcion2>MontoTotalCreditosCursaraEstudiante</descripcion2>
        </Descripciones2>
    </Detalle>


    <PieDePagina>
        <Campos3>
            <campo3>TotalEstudiantes</campo3>
            <campo3>TotalCreditos</campo3>
            <campo3>MontoTotalCreditos</campo3>
        </Campos3>

        <TipoDatos3>
            <td3>Numerico</td3>
            <td3>Numerico</td3>
            <td3>Numerico</td3>
        </TipoDatos3>

        <Longitudes3>
            <lenght3>4</lenght3>
            <lenght3>6</lenght3>
            <lenght3>8</lenght3>
        </Longitudes3>

        <Descripciones3>
            <descripcion3>TotalEstudiantesConCreditoEducativoEnInforme</descripcion3>
            <descripcion3>TotalCreditosCursaranTodosEstudiantesEnInforme</descripcion3>
            <descripcion3>MontoTotalRequeridoPorCreditosEnInforme</descripcion3>
        </Descripciones3>
    </PieDePagina>

</Layout>
```

**XSD**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complextype name='Layouttype'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='Encabezado' type='xs:Encabezadotype'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='Detalle' type='xs:Detalletype'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='PieDePagina' type='xs:PieDePaginatype'> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complextype>

    <xs:complextype name='Encabezadotype'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='Campos1' type='xs:Campos1type'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='TipoDatos1' type='xs:TipoDatos1type'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='Longitudes1' type='xs:Longitudes1type'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='Descripciones1' type='xs:Descripciones1type'> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='Campos1type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='Campo1' type='string'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='TipoDatos1type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='td1' type='string'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='Longitudes1type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='Lenght1' type='integer'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='Descripciones1type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='Descripcion1' type='string'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>



    <xs:complextype name='Detalletype'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='Campos2' type='xs:Campos2type'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='TipoDatos2' type='xs:TipoDatos2type'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='Longitudes2' type='xs:Longitudes2type'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='Descripciones2' type='xs:Descripciones2type'> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='Campos2type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='Campo2' type='string'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='TipoDatos2type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='td2' type='string'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='Longitudes2type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='Lenght2' type='integer'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='Descripciones2type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='Descripcion2' type='string'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>  



    <xs:complextype name='PieDePaginatype'>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name='Campos3' type='xs:Campos3type'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='TipoDatos3' type='xs:TipoDatos3type'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='Longitudes3' type='xs:Longitudes3type'> </xs:element>
            <xs:element name='Descripciones3' type='xs:Descripciones3type'> </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='Campos3type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='Campo3' type='string'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='TipoDatos3type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='td3' type='string'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='Longitudes3type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='Lenght3' type='integer'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>

            <xs:complextype name='Descripciones3type'>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name='Descripcion3' type='string'> </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complextype>                    

</xs:schema>
```

I think too my XSD is not correctly made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct; your XSD is not correctly formulated.  Among the problems:

1. You have many instances of an element named `complextype`, but XSD has no such element; it has a `complexType` element which I assume is what you have in mind.
2. Your schema document specifies no target namespace, and so the complex types and elements you declare are not associated with any namespace.  But you refer to them as if they were the XSD namespace, using the prefix `xs`.  You want that prefix for the built-in types `integer` and `string` but not for `Campos1type` etc.
3. Your schema document and your XML do not agree on how to spell some of your elements:  your declaration of `Campos1type` specifies a child element named `Campo1`, but in your XML, the `Campos1` element has children named `campo1`.
4. None of your declarations allow child elements to repeat.

There may be other problems; this is where I stopped looking.

Since most XSD validators default to looking for a top-level element declaration matching the outermost element of the input, you'll probably also want a declaration of the form

```
<xs:element name="Layout" type="Layouttype"/>
```